# Winforms Textbox Autocomplete Crash Application

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

Sometimes the program crashes when I write in the textbox. I can't find the solution. It is very weird situation. Why is program crashes sometimes. Here codes:

```
 Private Sub CreateProductNameAutoCompleteSource(ByVal tamamlamaturu As Byte)
    Dim sql_ProductName As String
    Dim gorkemDAL As New Aktuel.Data.SqlClient(cns_ScalaConnectionString)
    Dim dtbl_ProductName As DataTable
    Dim X As New AutoCompleteStringCollection

    Dim parcakodu
    If tamamlamaturu = tamamlamatipi.talepedilenparca Then parcakodu = txt_talepedilenparca.Text
    If tamamlamaturu = tamamlamatipi.gonderilenparca Then parcakodu = txt_gonderilenparca.Text

    sql_ProductName = "select distinct urunkodu from urunler where urunkodu like '" & parcakodu & "%' order by urunkodu asc"

    gorkemDAL.OpenDbConnection()
    dtbl_ProductName = gorkemDAL.ExecuteTable(sql_ProductName)
    gorkemDAL.CloseDbConnection()

    For Each row As DataRow In dtbl_ProductName.Rows
        X.Add(row(0).ToString)
    Next
    If tamamlamaturu = tamamlamatipi.talepedilenparca Then
        txt_talepedilenparca.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        txt_talepedilenparca.AutoCompleteCustomSource = X
        txt_talepedilenparca.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    End If

    If tamamlamaturu = tamamlamatipi.gonderilenparca Then
        txt_gonderilenparca.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        txt_gonderilenparca.AutoCompleteCustomSource = X
        txt_gonderilenparca.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

    End If

End Sub
```

And Textchange event :

```
Private Sub txt_talepedilenparca_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_talepedilenparca.TextChanged
    CreateProductNameAutoCompleteSource(tamamlamatipi.talepedilenparca)
End Sub
```

And I found error message in event viewer: 
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xsDa.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJdxd.png)

Comment: What type of crash? What's the error message?

Comment: before anything else you should stop building queries like this and use parametrized queries. The values are coming from textboxes so this is wide open for sql injection. Also it will solve any issues with quotes and other characters that a user might type in the textbox

Comment: @the_lotus there is no error message. Program is closing.

Comment: @GuidoG you are right. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks pretty clean, I can't see anything too obvious but I would make sure that parcakodu doesn't contain any sql terminating speech marks:

i.e.

```
sql_ProductName = "select distinct urunkodu from urunler where urunkodu like '" & parcakodu & "%' order by urunkodu asc"
```

becomes:

```
sql_ProductName = "select distinct urunkodu from urunler where urunkodu like '" & parcakodu.Replace("'", "''") & "%' order by urunkodu asc"
```

(you may want to copy & paste as hard to see what I've done there)

I would also wrap your ForEach statement in a null check - could it be you're trying to access dtbl_ProductName when it's null? Accessing the property .Rows will raise an exception if the object is null itself is Nothing.

Try something like:

```
If (dtbl_ProductName IsNot Nothing)
    For Each row As DataRow In dtbl_ProductName.Rows
        X.Add(row(0).ToString)
    Next
End If
```

Failing that - check if you can make it crash every time by using a known search string that has caused it to crash in the past. Is there a character in the string sql doesn't like, or is the result set of your sql query empty?

Comment: I would recommend using parametrized queries. In stead of altering the sql statement here why dont you recomment using paramters in stead. Not only will it solve your point but it also excludes any change on sql injection and is easier to read and maintain

Comment: thank you for your comment. i tried your codes but it is still crashing. Sometimes working, sometimes crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this trick:

```
    Private Sub txt_talepedilenparca_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_talepedilenparca.TextChanged

Dim sql_ProductName As String
    Dim gorkemDAL As New Aktuel.Data.SqlClient(cns_ScalaConnectionString)
    Dim dtbl_ProductName As DataTable
    Dim X As New AutoCompleteStringCollection

sql_ProductName = "select distinct urunkodu from urunler where urunkodu order by urunkodu asc"

    gorkemDAL.OpenDbConnection()
    dtbl_ProductName = gorkemDAL.ExecuteTable(sql_ProductName)
    gorkemDAL.CloseDbConnection()

try
        If txt_talepedilenparca.lenght >= 3 and txt_talepedilenparca.lenght mod 3 = 0 then 
                    For Each row As DataRow In dtbl_ProductName.select("urunkodu like '*" & parcakodu & "*'")
            X.Add(row(0).ToString)
        Next
if x.count > 0
txt_talepedilenparca.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        txt_talepedilenparca.AutoCompleteCustomSource = X
        txt_talepedilenparca.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
end if
    End If
catch ex as exception
msgbox(ex.tostring)
end try
    End Sub
```

Comment: post the exception

Answer (score 0):

In your reply to the question about the error you're receiving you said the program is just closing.
Thus, the first step is to wrap your code in a Try...Catch block in order to get a meaningful error message without getting the program to close.

```
Private Sub CreateProductNameAutoCompleteSource(ByVal tamamlamaturu As Byte)
    Try
        Dim sql_ProductName As String
        Dim gorkemDAL As New Aktuel.Data.SqlClient(cns_ScalaConnectionString)
        Dim dtbl_ProductName As DataTable
        Dim X As New AutoCompleteStringCollection

        Dim parcakodu
        If tamamlamaturu = tamamlamatipi.talepedilenparca Then
            parcakodu = txt_talepedilenparca.Text
        ElseIf tamamlamaturu = tamamlamatipi.gonderilenparca Then
            parcakodu = txt_gonderilenparca.Text
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        sql_ProductName = "select distinct urunkodu from urunler where urunkodu like '" & parcakodu.Replace("'", "''") & "%' order by urunkodu asc"

        gorkemDAL.OpenDbConnection()
        dtbl_ProductName = gorkemDAL.ExecuteTable(sql_ProductName)
        gorkemDAL.CloseDbConnection()

        If (dtbl_ProductName IsNot Nothing) Then
            For Each row As DataRow In dtbl_ProductName.Rows
                X.Add(row(0).ToString)
            Next
        End If

        If tamamlamaturu = tamamlamatipi.talepedilenparca Then
            txt_talepedilenparca.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            txt_talepedilenparca.AutoCompleteCustomSource = X
            txt_talepedilenparca.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        End If

        If tamamlamaturu = tamamlamatipi.gonderilenparca Then
            txt_gonderilenparca.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            txt_gonderilenparca.AutoCompleteCustomSource = X
            txt_gonderilenparca.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The following error has occured:{0}{1}", vbCrLf, ex.Message), "An error has occured")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub txt_talepedilenparca_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_talepedilenparca.TextChanged
    If txt_talepedilenparca.Text.Length >= 3 Then
        CreateProductNameAutoCompleteSource(tamamlamatipi.talepedilenparca)
    End If
End Sub
```

This will give a clear idea about what's happening before tackling the main issue.

I've also escaped the string value being passed to the query so it doesn't create an SQL injection if the user entered a single quote in the text boxes.
I've also limited the function not trigger but until the textbox has at least 3 letters.

If the program still closes without an error message, then the issue is happening elsewhere, but if you got an error message, then we can take it from there.

Comment: i tried try catch block but there is no error the program still closing.

Comment: Then I would suggest that the issue is somewhere else. You should be able to find a crash report in the Events Viewer.

Comment: i found error message in events viewer. it is about ntdll.dll.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the error message, like paste the full error message or a screenshot?!

Comment: i added screenshots to main subject. Here links: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xsDa.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJdxd.png